# Angular5, response and subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular

i have 2 calls to server that depends on each other like this

```
    this.service.fetchPoints(this.dateStart, this.dateEnd).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.points = response;
            do something .....
        }
    );

    this.service.fetchSchedule(this.points.date).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.schedule = response;
        }
    );
```

this.service is code like this:

```
fetchPoints(from:string, to:string) {
    return this.http.get(this.createUrl(`/api/congregations/fetch_points/${this.congregation.id}-${from}-${to}`));
}
```

second function also returns `observable` the easiest way to make dependency is to write it like this

```
      this.service.fetchPoints(this.dateStart, this.dateEnd).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.points = repsonse;
            this.service.fetchSchedule(this.points.date).subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.schedule = response;
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

but this looks ugly, is there a way to make it better?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you are doing it? It makes complete sense since you need the data from `fetchPoints` becore you can call `fetchSchedule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your `Observable` to a `Promise`, but you will be acheving the same thing really.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

fetchPoints(from:string, to:string) {
    return this.http.get(this.createUrl(`/api/congregations/fetch_points/${this.congregation.id}-${from}-${to}`))
          .toPromise();
}
```

Service:

```
  this.service.fetchPoints(this.dateStart, this.dateEnd).then(
    response => {
        this.points = repsonse;
        this.service.fetchSchedule(this.points.date).then(
            response => {
                this.schedule = response;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

But the above does not really "tidy" much up, so what I would suggest is that you move the `fetchSchedule` into it's own method.

Also in the above code I noticed you are using the scoped variable `response` twice, that is quite confusing, so if you don't take any of my suggestions, I suggest that you change `response` into something like `pointsResponse` and `scheduleResponse`.

```
private getSchedule() {
    this.service.fetchSchedule(this.points.date).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.schedule = response;
        }
    );
}
```

Your code would then look like:

```
  this.service.fetchPoints(this.dateStart, this.dateEnd).subscribe(
    response => {
        this.points = repsonse;
            getSchedule();
        );
    }
);
```